# object detection and large datasets image

Tags: python

For object detection projects, containing too many parameters leads to a large amount of GPU memory. In addition, these problems require a lot of image data. Since then, when I train the model, I always have a memory problem (even though I bought the pro version of colab). So what should I do to handle this problem. And can anyone share me some experience when dealing with large image data?

Comment: Get colab pro or AWS SageMaker

Comment: in colab pro, i only have 17gb GPU , with yolov5 , and 364 images i can only use batch_size = 4.